# A subset that can be scaled to be the whole space, or that can contain a scaled version of the whole space

Tags: vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

The following is from Mariano's comments on [my earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95984/1281)

1. In a topological vector space, why is the following true:

   > if a neighborhood U of zero contains a scaled copy of the whole space,
   >   then it is in fact the whole space.

   Is "a neighborhood U of zero contains a scaled copy of the whole
   space" the same as "a scaled copy of a neighborhood U of zero is the
   whole space"?

   I have thought about this for a while but don't know why.
2. In a vector space, is it true that if a subset U of zero contains a
   scaled copy of the whole space, then it is in fact the whole space? I think it is not true when the base field of the vector space is a finite set?

   Is "a subset U of zero contains a scaled copy of the whole
   space" the same as "a scaled copy of a subset U of zero is the
   whole space"?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: well, a scaled copy of the whole space *is* the whole space!

Comment: @t.b.: Really, in both TVS and vector space? Then Mariano introduced some unnecessary complication to that quote.

Comment: @DavidMitra: How is the first equality true?

Comment: Sorry, I should have   said: $\alpha V=V$, for $\alpha\ne0$. One inclusion is obvious. For the other inclusion, note if $v\in V$,  then $v=\alpha(\alpha^{-1}v)\in\alpha V$.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMitra and t.b.!