# Weak closure of $\{\sqrt n e_n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ and metrizability of weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{e_n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ be an orthonormal basis of Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and put $I = \left\{\sqrt n e_n|n\in \mathbb N\right \}$. Show that $0$ belongs to the weak closure of I but no sequence from $I$ is weakly convergent to $0$. Conclude from this that weak topology on $\mathcal H$ does not satisfy the first axiom of countability and hence is not metrizable.

Comment: What does "n1/2en" mean?  Is it supposed to be $\sqrt n e_n$?  Is your question the same as this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42337/?

Comment: that  power of n is half and en is e sub script n

Comment: Do you see how the conclusion follows if you can show the first part?  The first part is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: You should really pick a better title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- $0$ is an element of the weak closure of $I$: fix a basic neighborhood of $0$ for the weak topology, say $O:=\bigcap_{j=1}^N\{x,|f_j(x)|<\delta\}$ where $\delta>0$ and $f_j$ are linear continuous functionals. We have to show that $O$ contains an element $\sqrt n\cdot e_n$ for some $n$. If not, representing the linear functional $f_j$ by the vector $y_j$, we would have
  $$\sum_{j=1}^N\|y_j\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^N|\langle e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2\geqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\delta^2}{n}=\infty.$$
- Let $\{x_n\}$ a sequence of $I$. If there are infinitely many different terms,
  say $\{\sqrt k\,e_k,\ k\in A\}$ where $A\subset\Bbb N$ is infinite, write the sequence $x_k:=\sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}$ where $n_k$ is an increasing sequence of integers. The sequence $\{x_k\}$ is not bounded an so cannot be weakly convergent. If there are only finitely many different terms, we extract a subsequence constant equal to one of them, proving we can't have convergence to $0$.
- If there were a decreasing countable basis of neighborhood at $0$ , say $\{V_n,n\in\Bbb N\}$ (for the weak topology), we would be able for each $n$, $x_{k_n}\in I\cap V_n$ by the first point (and the definition of the closure). And this sequence would converge weakly to $0$, a contradiction by the second item of the list.
- A metric space $(S,d)$ satisfies the first axiom of countability, as if $x\in S$, the collection $\{B_d(x,n^{-1}),n\in\Bbb N^*\}$ would be a countable basis of neighborhoods.

Comment: i am confused with this proof could u make it clear for second and third . what about last point it is totally not fit in the proof.

Comment: could you help me to join this thing sensibally so it seems good solution

Comment: I've added details. If you have a problem, don't hesitate.

Comment: Is it really possible to get $n_k\leq Nk$? There seems to be a problem, because maybe the first million entries are taken by a $j_j$ that only appears finitely many times. A fairly straightforward way of dealing with this is to notice that $$
\sum_{j=1}^N\|y_j\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle \sqrt n\,e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^N|\langle \sqrt n\,e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\delta^2}{n}=\infty, 
$$ a contradiction.

Comment: Formula in my previous comment is wrong, should have been $$\sum_{j=1}^N\|y_j\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^N|\langle e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\delta^2}{n}=\infty.$$

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you very much for having pointed this out. This is indeed a good way to solve the issue and I am grateful to you for having proposed it.

Comment: No problem. I had upvoted your answe many years ago, so I guess it took me a while to notice ;)

Comment: May I ask how does this not violate the result: a cluster point of a net is the limit of a sub-net? A sequence is also a net. So why in this case the mentioned result fails? Thanks

Comment: Unless, by "in the closure", it refers to $I = \left\{\sqrt n e_n|n\in \mathbb N\right \}$ as a set, not a sequence?