# A function $f: H \to \mathbb{R}$ is not weakly continuous at $0$ but $(f(x_n)$ converges to $0$ whenever $(x_n) \to 0$ weakly in $H$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space equipped with its weak topology and let $K \subset H$ such that $K = \{ \sqrt{n}e_n | n \in \mathbb{N_0} \}$ Let $f:H \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x) = 1$ when $ x \in K$ and $0$ otherwise.

Prove that $f$ is not weakly continuous at $0$ but  $(f(x_n))$ converges to $0$ whenever $(x_n) \to 0$ weakly in $H$

I have been working on this but I am not sure my ideas are correct. I see that in the norm topology $f$ is not continuous in $0$ but I am unable to form a valid argument to show that $f$ is also not weakly continuous at $0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am a self-studying student and have no other support group.

Comment: Show that $0$ is in the weak closure of $K$. (For the second part, show that no sequence in $K$ converges weakly to $0$.)

Comment: Towards that end, see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231176/weak-closure-of-sqrt-n-e-nn-in-mathbb-n-and-metrizability-of-weak-topol).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have proved what you have said previously, but I am unable to put all the ideas together. Moreover, I am unsure of my proof for the two statements you have mentioned. So I came seeking help.

Comment: There is a net in $K$ that converges weakly to $0$. But the image of this net under $f$ does not converge weakly to $0$. So, $f$ is not weakly continuous.

Comment: The concept of a net! I have completely overlooked that. Thank you. Let me see if I can make any headway with this.