# Does the square function respect the strong operator topology on self-adjoint operators?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

A real-valued continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is referred to as "strongly continuous", if for every Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and every pointwise convergent net $a_\lambda\to a$ of self-adjoint operators in $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$, one has $f(a_\lambda)\to f(a)$ pointwise. In other words, applying functional calculus with this function on self-adjoints is continuous in the strong operator topology.

Most of the time this concept pops up only briefly before the proof of Kaplansky's density theorem, in tandem with the fact that any function with at most linear growth (as $t\to\pm\infty$) is strongly continuous. (In the newest edition of Pedersen's book "C*-algebras and their automorphism groups", this is Proposition 2.3.2.)

My question: **Is the square function $f(t)=t^2$ strongly continuous?**

I am currently in the last stretches of teaching a course on operator algebras, and was recently not able to rigorously answer this question by one of my students. I strongly suspect that the answer is no, but I struggle to come up with a specific counterexample. I have looked through the usual textbooks, but did not see an answer there, either. Can anybody help me come up with a rigorous answer or possibly point me to a reference where this has been done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not.

Here is (one of?) the canonical example(s). Note that an example cannot be bounded, since multiplication is jointly sot-continuous on bounded sets.

Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ of $H$. Consider the set $\{\sqrt n\,e_n\}$. If $0\not\in\overline{\{\sqrt n\,e_n\}}^w$, then there exists an open neighbourhood
$$
W=\{x:\ |f_j(x)|<\delta,\ j=1,\ldots,N\}
$$
such that $W\cap\overline{\{\sqrt n\,e_n\}}^w=\varnothing$. Via the Riesz Representation Theorem this means that there exist $y_1,\ldots,y_N\in H$ and indices $j_n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ with
$$
\delta\leq |\langle \sqrt n\,e_n,y_{j_n}\rangle|,\qquad n\in\mathbb N. 
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N\|y_j\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle \sqrt n\,e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^N|\langle \sqrt n\,e_n,y_{j}\rangle|^2\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\delta^2}{n}=\infty, 
$$
a contradiction.

So $0\in\overline{\{\sqrt n\,e_n\}}^w$. This means that there exists a net $\{n_j\}$ of integers such that $\sqrt{n_j}\,e_{n_j}\to0$ weakly.

Define operators $T_j\in B(H)$ by
$$
T_jx=\sqrt{n_j}\,\langle x,e_{n_j}\rangle\,e_{n_j}. 
$$
Then
$$
\|T_jx\|=|\sqrt{n_j}\,\langle x,e_{n_j}\rangle|\to0, 
$$
so $T_j\to0$ sot. Meanwhile, we have $T_j^2x=n_j\,\langle x,e_{n_j}\rangle\,e_{n_j}$. Let $\{n_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a set of distinct integers such that, as sets, $\{n_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}=\{n_j\}_j$. Put $x=\sum_k\tfrac1{n_k}\,e_{n_k}\in H$. Then
$$
\|T_j^2x\|=1
$$
for all $j$, showing that $T_j^2$ does not converge sot to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This might be a case of me not seeing the forest from all the trees, but what version of Hahn-Banach are you using here? Naively I would think that you can only conclude that 0 is contained in the closed convex hull of $\sqrt{n}e_n$, which is naturally not enough. What am I missing?

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's another more subtle argument that one needs. I'll edit a bit later.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Just commenting to add a reference from the literature: the fact that $0$ belongs to the sot closure of the rank-1 operators $T_n := \sqrt{n} e_n \otimes \overline{e_n}$ appears in Example C.10 on page 277 of *Morita Equivalence and Continuous-Trace $C^\ast$-Algebras* by Raeburn and Williams.

Comment: @MikeF: thanks. For completeness, I'll just mention that this is way older than Raeburn-Williams. [Jonas Mayer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42497/22857) mentions that it appears in Halmos' *Hilbert Space Problem Book*.

Comment: It seems to me that the series defining $x$ is not garanteed to be convergent. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you put $\ell^2$ coefficients in front of an orthonormal set you get an element of the Hilbert space. What problem do you see?

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about the $\ell^2$ and was thinking that $\sum 1/n$ being divergent was a problem.

Comment: I am confused as to why this example does not violate the uniform boundedness principle. If $T_j \to 0$ sot, then we can conclude $\sup_j \lVert T_j\rVert < \infty$. But this does not hold for your example.

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that a convergent net is bounded. For each $x$, the net $\{T_jx\}$ converges to $0$ but it is not necessarily bounded.